# .resx file data inaccessible in Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file

What I'm trying to do: include some files along with the executable to extract them later.

I have two projects, both with a Resource1.resx file (and some resources included from disk).

- In one project, I can use `File.WriteAllBytes(path,
  Resource1.Image);` to dump the resource to disk.
- In another,
  `Resource1` is does not exist.

I've done this before but all I can find is information about localizations (?) when I search MSDN for how to work with Resources.

Edit: if it makes a difference, I'm using .NET 2.0 (yeah I know)

Comment: Don't forget to recompile the project after you add something to resources. That one got me a few times.

Comment: @AndrejBratoz could you comment on that? I have a blank project with some resources added and I'm struggling to write code to access them via a class. I go "Build > Build Solution" which I imagine does a compilation?

Comment: Well if you check the Resources folder you usually have a *.Designer.cs class that contains the getters for your resources. This is the way to access them, but the resources have to be compiled before you can access them. I usually build the whole project (or solution if consists of only one project) so I can access them.

Comment: @AndrejBratoz Yes, the getters in Designer.cs files for BOTH projects are identical (the names for resources are different) - one project I can access classes, another I cannot. All items are set to all possible options (embedded, compiled, ect) with no results.

Comment: is the class constructor where the getters are marked `public`? Because it's marked `internal` by default (which would mean the are accessible only within it's own the assembly).

Comment: @AndrejBratoz Is this what you mean? http://i.imgur.com/c4LXEdn.png If so, then no that doesn't seem to make the class available

Comment: No. The class that contains the getters is usually named 'AppResources' So that is the name you should be looking for. You can check it in the .*Designer.cs file. To access the class use the [ProjectNamespace].Resources.AppResources.[YourResource].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rename your project using the Solution Browser, it will not change all of the relevant instances of that name.

So by extension, calling `ResxItemName` won't do you any good because it's actually `OriginalNameSpace.ResxItemName`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the build action of the resx file. It should be set to compile (from the top of my head) to make it a compiled resource.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick of adding a ResourceClassName class. Maybe I need something like a `using` statement?